# [__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c2125a0

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone explain why i am getting this error?

> [__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7c2125a0

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [imageHolderForMainView removeFromSuperview];

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];   // iam getting the above mentioned error here

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    });
```

Comment: Did you debug your code, when it crashes?

Comment: Somewhere a `NSNumber` is passed where a `NSString` is expected, the error does not occur in these lines of code.

Comment: Please add exception break point and then execute the code.

Comment: There is something wrong in question. Error and code are not match.

Comment: If that's really the line where it's crashing since the error message is not "related" to that line, my guess is that somewhere you used either assign/weak on a strong property. In other words something that messed with memory.

Answer (score 1):

You are using NSString But it is a NSNumber.Check your object it is string or number. You can check your object from below code

```
 if ([yourObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
 { // It is Number
 }

 if ([yourObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
 {
   // it is string
 }
```